# Using history.replaceState breaks browser back/forward buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in my Ruby on Rails application I have implemented sorting and pagination to work with ajax. Nothing special. I've also added code that updates browser url using `history.replaceState`, so user click ajax sort link, and browser address bar is updated so user can copy this url and use it later. I've done this like that:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-remote=true]', function() {
  history.replaceState(null, '', $(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});
```

My code fails in the following scenario:

In Mozilla Firefox:

1. Visit main page: /dashboard
2. Visit page with ajax sorting: /patients
3. Click a one of the table columns to sort data via ajax
4. Click browser back button - redirects me to /dashboard which is ok
5. Click browser forward button it redirects me to /patients?order_by=name, I want to  be redirected to /patients

In Google Chrome:

1. Visit main page: /dashboard
2. Visit page with ajax sorting: /patients
3. Click a one of the table columns to sort data via ajax
4. Click browser back button - redirects me to /dashboard which is ok
5. Click browser forward button it redirects me to /patients?order_by=name but page contains only js response, no layout or anything like that.

Comment: Use pushState to allow navigation back to the page where the pushState lives, use replaceState to jump over the page the replaceState lives on the way back

Comment: Could You provide more details?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: I've read that but that doesn't solve my problem.